# bisect.bisect_right() is 3~4x faster than mine

Tags: python

I wrote my bisect_right(). It is 3x slower than bisect.bisect_right().

```
def my_bisect_right(a, num):
  ok = len(a)
  ng = -1
  while abs(ok - ng) > 1:
    mid = (ok + ng) // 2
    if a[mid] <= num:
      ng = mid
    else:
      ok = mid
  return ok
```

I created a list of 10M integers and ran bisect_right() against it.
The bisect.bisect_right() took 24.82 sec while my_bisect_right() took 76.30 sec.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: probably the `abs()` in your while condition, not much else different between them - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Lib/bisect.py#L19

Comment: thank you. after removing the abs(), I got 58.23 sec on the same size list.

Comment: Is the `bisect` module written in Python or C?

Comment: Are the times you posted single trials or are they averaged over several trials?

Comment: averaged. how can I find out if bisect module is written in Python or C? I thought it was written in Python...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using CPython and `_bisect` is available, the biggest difference is that `bisect.bisect_right()` is implemented in C. See [these lines in `bisect.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.5/Lib/bisect.py#L72-L76):

```
# Overwrite above definitions with a fast C implementation
try:
    from _bisect import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

---

For reference, you can easily check if a function is implemented in Python or C by its repr:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_right  # C
<built-in function bisect_right>
>>> import functools
>>> functools.wraps  # Python
<function wraps at 0x000001DDAB175F70>
```